# Detect vertical or horizontal position iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iPhone 4 and I would like to detect whether the phone is vertically straight (see first image) or horizontal (see second image). I am not talking about portrait vs landscape view detection.

I am new to iOS development and I think what I am looking for is the accelerometer (specifically the pitch property perhaps) or gyroscope. I have looked online and I am not quite understanding the code or whether I am looking for the right properties. Can someone please tell me how this can be done?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What don't you understand about the code?

Comment: @CodeBandits What I am looking for I guess. Like when I look at apple's example it seems very complex. Thanks

Comment: Well, you say your new to iOS, maybe you should take a look at some more basic tutorials before taking this on? Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `accelerometer` api and check the position of the phone.

here is a tutorial: http://tech.pro/tutorial/968/iphone-tutorial-reading-the-accelerometer